# VirtualBox на Ubuntu требует VT-x enabled

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

На машине **Intel® Core™ i9-9900KF CPU @ 3.60GHz × 16** стоит **Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS**. Установил Oracle VirtualBox версии **6.1.10_Ubuntu r138449**. VirtualBox не дает установить 64-разрядные версии Windows, а при попытке установить 32-разрядную выдает такую ошибку:

> VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED)

При перезагрузке по F2 менял флаг **VT-x** с **disabled** на **enabled**. Но это никак не помогло.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33304393/vt-x-is-disabled-in-the-bios-for-both-all-cpu-modes-verr-vmx-msr-all-vmx-disabl

Comment: Этот совет я пробовал. Но установить VT-x в BIOS как enabled не помогает, равно как и снятие галочки с опции Enable PAE/NX